# What is the required format for assembly versions?

Tags: c#, .net, versioning, .net-assembly, assemblyinfo

The [`Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxyt63s.aspx) class in .NET represents version numbers as consisting of two to four components.  AssemblyInfo files specify the following format for the `AssemblyVersion` and `AssemblyFileVersion` fileds:

```
// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
```

It is unclear if `Build Number` and `Revision` are required here, since they aren't required in the `Version` class.  Are they required?  In other words, is this legal?

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0")]
```

Or does that need to be represented as the following?

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that the [`AssemblyVersion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.assemblyversionattribute.aspx) may be in a variety of forms:

```
Examples of valid version strings include:
1
1.1
1.1.*
1.1.1
1.1.1.*
1.1.1.1
```

But [`AssemblyFileVersion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyfileversionattribute.assemblyfileversionattribute.aspx) must be of the form *major.minor.build.revision*:

> The file version is normally a string of four numbers, separated by periods, reflecting the major version number, minor version number, build number, and revision number; for example, "1.0.4309.00". If version is not in this format, a compiler warning occurs, and the results displayed in the file properties dialog are unpredictable. Wildcards are not supported.